# Firefox plugin - sockets

Tags: firefox, dom, sockets, plugins

I've always wanted a way to make a socket connection to a server and allow the server to manipulate the page DOM.  For example, this could be used in a stock quotes page, so the server can push new quotes as they become available.

I know this is a classic limitation (feature?) of HTTP's request/response protocol, but I think this could be implemented as a Firefox plugin (cross-browser compatibility is not important for my application).  Java/Flash solutions are not acceptable, because (as far as i know) they live in a box and can't interact with the DOM.

Can anyone confirm whether this is within the ability of a Firefox plugin?  Has someone already created this or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) which is a fancy name for a long running HTTP connection where the server can push updates to the page.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible.  I have developed a xulrunner application that connects to a TCP server using sockets.  Extension development would likely have the same capabilities.  I used a library from mozdev - [JSLib](http://jslib.mozdev.org/).  Specifically check out the [networking code](http://jslib.mozdev.org/libraries/network/network.html).  The fact that there is a [Firefox add-on for JSlib add-on for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search?q=jslib&cat=all) makes more more confident.

Essentially, as I understand it, sockets are not part of JavaScript, but through XPCOM, you can get raw socket access like you would in any c/c++ application.

Warning:  *JSLib doesn't seem to receive a lot of attention and the mailing list is pretty sparse.*

Answer (score 1):

> Java/Flash solutions are not acceptable, because (as far as i know)
>   they live in a box and can't interact with the DOM.

That's not actually true of Java.  You can interact with Java via JavaScript and make DOM changes.

http://stephengware.com/proj/javasocketbridge/

In this example there are two JavaScript methods for interaction

Send:

`socket_send("This was sent via the socket\n\n");`

Receive:

`on_socket_get(message){ more_code(message); }`

Answer (score 0):

> You may want to look at Comet

a.k.a. [server push](http://ejohn.org/blog/streaming-http-server-push/). This does not let the server "update" the client page directly, but all the new data is sent to the page through a single connection.

Of course, a Firefox [extension](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Extension) (as well as [plugins](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Plugins), which are binary libraries that can do whatever any other application can do) can work with sockets too. See [1](http://www.xulplanet.com/tutorials/mozsdk/serverpush.php), [2](http://www.xulplanet.com/tutorials/mozsdk/serverpush.php).